# Gluon-Mobile application plays no sound

Tags: java, javafx, gluon-mobile

I'm working on a YouTube-player and used the JavaFX WebView and YouTube-Embedded_Player for playing the videos.
This worked fine until I switched to Gluon-Mobile (the relevant code was not changed). Now if I want to play a video, the video is showing but there is no sound (also I tested to play sound files with some mechanisms but there is the same problem).
The odd thing is: in my sound mixer of Windows, the application is listed and sound is visualized but I can not hear anything; I tested the application on an other computer and there it worked.
JDK: 1.8 (x64)

Code:

```
public class PlayerPresenter extends GluonPresenter<Main> implements Initializable{
   private static final String PLAYER_HTML = Context.class.getResource("videoContainer.html").toString();
   [...]
   @FXML private View view;
   @FXML private WebView webView;
   [...]
   @Override
   public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources){
      webView.getEngine().load(PLAYER_HTML);
   }
   [...]
   private void play(){
      webView.getEngine().executeScript("playVideo('" + video.id + "', '" + video.type.name() + "')");
      // video is an instance from a class which holds informations about a YouTube video / playlist
   }
   [...]
}
```

videoConatiner.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8;charset=utf-8"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="videoControl.js"></script>
    <style>
        html, body{
            height: 100%;
            width: 100%;
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

videoControl.js

```
var player;
var id;
var mode;
var ready = false;
var onReady = null;

setUp();

function setUp(){
    this.ready = false;
    var tag = document.createElement('script');
    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
}
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
        height: "100%",
        width: "100%",
        events: {
           'onReady': onPlayerReady,
           'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
        },
        playerVars: {
            fs: 0,
            rel: 0
        }
    });
}

function onPlayerReady(event) {
    this.ready = true;
    if(this.onReady != null) this.onReady();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING) {
        var videoData = player.getVideoData();
        this.id = videoData.video_id;
    }
}

function playVideo(id, type){
    if(!isReady()){
        this.onReady = function (){
            this.onReady = null;
            playVideo0(id, type);
        }
    }else{
        playVideo0(id, type);
    }
    return null;
}
function playVideo0(id, type){
    this.id = id;
    this.mode = type;

    switch (mode){
        case "VIDEO":
            player.loadVideoById({
                videoId:id
            });
            break;
        case "PLAYLIST":
            player.loadPlaylist({
                list:id,
                listType:"playlist",
                index:0
           });
           break;
    }
    return null;
}
function stop(){
    player.stopVideo();
}
function getVideoId(){
    return this.id;
}
function isReady(){
    return this.ready;
}
```

So my question is: is it a bug in my applicaton or does my computer cause the problem (and how can I solve this).
Thanks for your help.

Comment: When using WebView on mobile, you are using the native component, not the JavaFX one, and JSObject is not supported. But Charm Down has a [VideoService](http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/5.0.2/com/gluonhq/charm/down/plugins/VideoService.html) specifically designed for playing video on mobile. See this [blog post](https://gluonhq.com/new-gluon-charm-services-part/).

Comment: @José Pereda The problem is at the dektop-application (Windows) (for Android I have an other solution).

Comment: Desktop uses the JavaFX WebView. There shouldn't be any difference from running a regular JavaFX app. Maybe you can share some code that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @José Pereda Ok I hope this will help ...

Comment: I've tried your code with a regular JavaFX app and with a Gluon Mobile app on desktop only, both cases work normally fine, with video and audio. I tested this: `webView.getEngine().executeScript("playVideo('M7lc1UVf-VE', 'VIDEO')");`

Comment: @José Pereda Ok, thank you very much. So it must be my computer; I'll see if I can do something about this.